# How to scala-test a Spark program under "local-cluster" mode?

Tags: apache-spark, classpath

I have a Spark program that has very complete test suites in local mode, but when deployed on a Spark cluster, it demonstrates several serialization and synchronization issues, which the test suites fail to detect.

As a result I want to migrate these tests to local-cluster mode. This is my SparkConf setting:

```
new SparkConf().setAppName("unit")
.setMaster("local-cluster[2,4,1024]")
.setAppName("DataPassportSparkTest")
.setSparkHome(System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
.set("spark.driver.classpath", sys.props("java.class.path"))
.set("spark.executor.classpath", sys.props("java.class.path"))
.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
```

However my attempt to add java classpath into Spark application seems to fail without a reason, so Spark always complaints that my class cannot be found. Is there a way to notify Spark the presence of my classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK that was a stupid mistake, all I need is to replace "classpath" with "extraClassPath":

```
new SparkConf().setAppName("unit")
.setMaster("local-cluster[2,4,1024]")
.setAppName("DataPassportSparkTest")
.setSparkHome(System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", sys.props("java.class.path"))
.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", sys.props("java.class.path"))
.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
```